# Can quantum computers handle 'big' data?

Tags: quantum-memory, memory-space

While there are many interesting questions that a computer can solve with barely any data (such as factorization, which requires "only" a single integer), most real-world applications, such as [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) or [AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence), will require large amounts of data.

Can quantum computers handle this massive stream of data, in theory or in practice? Is it a good idea to store the data in a "quantum memory", or is it better to store it in a "classical memory"?

Answer (score 4):

It's not so much a matter of big data, but that of saving data. Quantum storage is still (much like the rest of the field) in its infancy.

(Take what I write with a grain of salt. It's likely to change rapidly.)

There are a few theories on how quantum computers might be able to hold "memory".

One of these is using nuclear spin. E.g. using long-lived nuclei in a quantum state. Converting an electron qubit (a qubit represented by an electron) to a nuclear qubit is [possible](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2021).

#### Why nuclear qubit/spin?

A nucleus's coherence time - the time for which its phase is constant (when considering its wave function) - is longer than that of an electron. The [linked article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2021) (same one as before) details how one can increase the coherence time of a nuclear spin (to some extent). The matter is being researched, but there is some indication that nuclear qubits can be a form of quantum storage.

#### What makes it difficult

The quantum state needs to remain, well, quantum. Additionally, if you entangle two of your "storage" qubits, you are likely to lose data.

Due to no-cloning, one cannot simply "copy" a qubit (whose state is unknown), which is one of the reasons quantum storage is difficult.

As for "big" data, it's just a matter of how much memory you have.

Answer (score -4):

As of now, I havent seen any advancements in Quantum Storage as the quantum higher state decays to 0 overtime even when isolated.

QC is meant to compute large workflows . As of now ,inputs  can be infinite sized , because it is described within the circuit in binary format . Outputs can only be qubit sized when an algorithm is running . The data processing part is where it gets tricky. Only very specific types of things work. but it works well.

Comment: What do you mean inputs can be infinite size?